# Does assigning objects to null in Java impact garbage collection?

Tags: java, null, garbage-collection

Does assigning an unused object reference to `null` in Java improve the garbage collection process in any measurable way?

My experience with Java (and C#) has taught me that is often counter intuitive to try and outsmart the virtual machine or JIT compiler, but I've seen co-workers use this method and I am curious if this is a good practice to pick up or one of those voodoo programming superstitions?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Typically, no.

But like all things: it depends. The GC in Java these days is VERY good and everything should be cleaned up very shortly after it is no longer reachable. This is just after leaving a method for local variables, and when a class instance is no longer referenced for fields.

You only need to explicitly null if you know it would remain referenced otherwise. For example an array which is kept around. You may want to null the individual elements of the array when they are no longer needed.

For example, this code from ArrayList:

```
public E remove(int index) {
    RangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = (E) elementData[index];

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
         System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
             numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work

    return oldValue;
}
```

Also, explicitly nulling an object will not cause an object to be collected any sooner than if it just went out of scope naturally as long as no references remain.

Both:

```
void foo() {
   Object o = new Object();
   /// do stuff with o
}
```

and:

```
void foo() {
   Object o = new Object();
   /// do stuff with o
   o = null;
}
```

Are functionally equivalent.

Comment: you might also want to null references inside methods that may use a large amount of memory or take a long time to execute, or in code in a Swing application that may run a long time.  In short methods or short lived objects, its not worth the extra confusing code.

Comment: So is it right, when we null an object the Garbage Collector collect that object immediately??

Comment: No. The garbage collector is periodically executed to see if there were any objects to which no reference variables are pointing to. When you set them to null and then call `System.gc()` then it will be removed (provided there are no other references pointing to that object).

Comment: @JavaTechnical As I know it is not guaranteed that by calling System.gc() garbage collection starts.

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, more often than not, people null out references out of paranoia not out of necessity. Here is a quick guideline:

1. If object A references object B **and** you no longer need this reference **and** object A is not eligible for garbage collection then you should explicitly null out the field. There is no need to null out a field if the enclosing object is getting garbage collected anyway. Nulling out fields in a dispose() method is almost always useless.
2. There is no need to null out object references created in a method. They will get cleared automatically once the method terminates. The exception to this rule is if you're running in a very long method or some massive loop and you need to ensure that some references get cleared before the end of the method. Again, these cases are extremely rare.

I would say that the vast majority of the time you will not need to null out references. Trying to outsmart the garbage collector is useless. You will just end up with inefficient, unreadable code.

Answer (score 11):

Good article is today's [coding horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/die-you-gravy-sucking-pig-dog/).

The way GC's work is by looking for objects that do not have any pointers to them, the area of their search is heap/stack and any other spaces they have.  So if you set a variable to null, the actual object is now not pointed by anyone, and hence could be GC'd.

But since the GC might not run at that exact instant, you might not actually be buying yourself anything.  But if your method is fairly long (in terms of execution time) it might be worth it since you will be increasing your chances of GC collecting that object.

The problem can also be complicated with code optimizations, if you never use the variable after you set it to null, it would be a safe optimization to remove the line that sets the value to null (one less instruction to execute).  So you might not actually be getting any improvement.

So in summary, **yes it can help, but it will not be deterministic**.

Comment: The link http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001211.html is now https://blog.codinghorror.com/die-you-gravy-sucking-pig-dog/

Comment: Good point on the safe optimization that removes the line setting the ref to null.

Comment: An optimizer may remove the `null` assignment, but by the same time, it’s understood that the variable is unused, hence, not counting as a reference preventing garbage collection.

Answer (score 8):

At least in java, it's not voodoo programming at all.  When you create an object in java using something like

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
```

you do two things: first, you create a reference to an object, and second, you create the Foo object itself.   So long as that reference or another exists, the specific object can't be gc'd.  however, when you assign null to that reference...

```
bar = null ;
```

and assuming nothing else has a reference to the object, it's freed and available for gc the next time the garbage collector passes by.

Comment: But going out of scope will do the same thing without the extra line of code.  If it's local to a method, there's no need.   Once you leave the method, the object will be eligible for GC.

Comment: Good.  now, for a pop quiz, construct an example of code for which that's NOT sufficient.  Hint: they exist.

Answer (score 7):

It depends.

Generally speaking shorter you keep references to your objects, faster they'll get collected.

If your method takes say 2 seconds to execute and you don't need an object anymore after one second of method execution, it makes sense to clear any references to it. If GC sees that after one second, your object is still referenced, next time it might check it in a minute or so.

**Anyway, setting all references to null by default is to me premature optimization and nobody should do it unless in specific rare cases where it measurably decreases memory consuption.**

Answer (score 7):

Explicitly setting a reference to null instead of just letting the variable go out of scope, does not help the garbage collector, unless the object held is very large, where setting it to null as soon as you are done with is a good idea.

Generally setting references to null, mean to the READER of the code that this object is completely done with and should not be concerned about any more.

A similar effect can be achieved by introducing a narrower scope by putting in an extra set of braces

```java
{
  int l;
  {  // <- here
    String bigThing = ....;
    l = bigThing.length();
  }  // <- and here
}
```

this allows the bigThing to be garbage collected right after leaving the nested braces.

Comment: Good alternative.  This avoids explicitly setting the variable to null _and_ the lint warning some IDEs display about that null assignment not being used.

Comment: This trick only works if the slot used for `bigThing` is reused for something else later in the method, otherwise the large object remains referenced by the slot until the end of the method. And if reuse does happen, the Java compiler is generally intelligent enough to reuse slots even without the scope.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class JavaMemory {
    private final int dataSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() * 0.6);

    public void f() {
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
            //data = null;
        }

        byte[] data2 = new byte[dataSize];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JavaMemory jmp = new JavaMemory();
        jmp.f();

    }

}
```

Above program throws `OutOfMemoryError`. If you uncomment `data = null;`, the `OutOfMemoryError` is solved. It is always good practice to set the unused variable to null

Comment: That is, imo, a solid foray into the world of straw man arguments. Just because you CAN create a situation where setting the variable to null will solve the issue in that particular case (and I'm not convinced that you have done such) does not imply that setting it to null is a good idea in every case. Adding in the code to set every variable you're not using anymore to null, even when they'd go out of scope shortly thereafter, just adds to code bloat and makes the code less maintainable.

Comment: Why isn't the byte[] array garbage collected at the moment the variable data is out of scope?

Comment: @Grav: going out of scope does not guarantee that the garbage collector will collect the local objects. However, setting it to null prevents the OutOfMemory exception, because you are guaranteed that the GC will run before resorting to throwing an OutOfMemory exception, and if the object was set to null it will be collectable.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260594/adding-for-loop-prevents-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 4):

I was working on a video conferencing application one time and noticed a huge huge huge difference in performance when I took the time to null references as soon as I didn't need the object anymore. This was in 2003-2004 and I can only imagine the GC has gotten even smarter since. In my case I had hundreds of objects coming and going out of scope every second, so I noticed the GC when it kicked in periodically. However after I made it a point to null objects the GC stopped pausing my application.

So it depends on what your doing...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the OP is referring to things like this:

```
private void Blah()
{
    MyObj a;
    MyObj b;

    try {
        a = new MyObj();
        b = new MyObj;

        // do real work
    } finally {
        a = null;
        b = null;
    }
}
```

In this case, wouldn't the VM mark them for GC as soon as they leave scope anyway?

Or, from another perspective, would explicitly setting the items to null cause them to get GC'd before they would if they just went out of scope? If so, the VM may spend time GC'ing the object when the memory isn't needed anyway, which would actually cause worse performance CPU usage wise because it would be GC'ing more earlier.

Comment: The time at which the GC runs is non-deterministic. I don't believe setting an object to `null` influences the GC behaviour at all.

Comment: A reference counting system would require immediate action if the assignment to `null` caused the count to go to zero. But in this case, leaving the method would have the same effect, as it also dereferences the objects. Traversing garbage collectors do not care about these assignments as they run whenever the execution environment thinks it’s a good time to run.

Answer (score 1):

Even if nullifying the reference were marginally more efficient, would it be worth the ugliness of having to pepper your code with these ugly nullifications? They would only be clutter and obscure the intent code that contains them.

Its a rare codebase that has no better candidate for optimisation than trying to outsmart the Garbage collector (rarer still are developers who succeed in outsmarting it). Your efforts will most likely be better spent elsewhere instead, ditching that crufty Xml parser or finding some opportunity to cache computation. These optimisations will be easier to quantify and don't require you dirty up your codebase with noise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

From "The Pragmatic Programmer" p.292:

By setting a reference to NULL you reduce the number of pointers to the object by one ... (which will allow the garbage collector to remove it)

Comment: I guess this is applicable only when reference count algo. is in use or otherwise also ?

Comment: This advice is obsolete for any modern garbage collector; and reference counting GC has significant problems, such as circular references.

Comment: It would also be true in a mark and sweep GC; probably in all others. The fact that you have one less reference doesn't not mean it's reference counted. The answer by tweakt explains this. It's better to reduce scope than set to NULL.

Comment: @LawrenceDol The answer is not obsolete. Also note that James Brooks did not talk about reference counting GC algorithms. Any GC implementation will not garbage collect an object if it is being referred to by a live object. Thus, as a general rule, removing references by setting them to null greatly affect the GC as it reduces the *possibility* that a live reference points to an object. Whether it affects a specific piece of code is, of course, a completely different subject and warrants a completely specific discussion.

Comment: @Torben : You’re wrong. But I’ll leave you to read up on how GC systems in general, and Java GC’s in particular, determine whether an object is eligible for collection on your own time.

Comment: @LawrenceDol No, you are incorrectly assuming that I am talking about what you are thinking. Please read what I and James actually *wrote*.

Comment: @Torben : I did read what you (and James) wrote, and as a whole it's incorrect -- parts are true, but the gist is not. It is simply not true that "as a general rule, removing references by setting them to null greatly affect[sic] the GC"; exactly the opposite is true. There *are* edge-cases where explicitly nulling is needed, but as a "general rule" it serves no purpose except to add bloat and unnecessary code. But, please, continue to argue and work hard to justify your statement -- I have work to do.

Comment: Recommended Q&A to read: [finalize() called on strongly reachable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488).

Answer (score 0):

"*It depends*"

I do not know about Java but in .net (C#, VB.net...) it is usually not required to assign a null when you no longer require a object.

However note that it is "usually not required".

By analyzing your code the .net compiler makes a good valuation of the life time of the variable...to accurately tell when the object is not being used anymore. So if you write obj=null it might actually look as if the obj is still being used...in this case it is counter productive to assign a null.

There are a few cases where it might actually help to assign a null. One example is you have a huge code that runs for long time or a method that is running in a different thread, or some loop. In such cases it might help to assign null so that it is easy for the GC to know its not being used anymore.

There is no hard & fast rule for this. Going by the above place null-assigns in your code and do run a profiler to see if it helps in any way. Most probably you might not see a benefit.

If it is .net code you are trying to optimize, then my experience has been that taking good care with Dispose and Finalize methods is actually more beneficial than bothering about nulls.

Some references on the topic:

http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/26/97229.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2004/02/20/77422.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the future execution of your program, the values of some data members will be used to computer an output visible external to the program. Others might or might not be used, depending on future (And impossible to predict) inputs to the program. Other data members might be guaranteed not to be used. All resources, including memory,  allocated to those unused data are wasted. The job of the garbage collector (GC) is to eliminate that wasted memory. It would be disastrous for the GC to eliminate something that was needed, so the algorithm used might be conservative,  retaining more than the strict minimum. It might use heuristic optimizations to improve its speed, at the cost of retaining some items that are not actually  needed. There are many potential algorithms the GC might use. Therefore it is possible that changes you make to your program, and which do not affect the correctness of your program, might nevertheless affect the operation of the GC, either making it run faster to do the same job, or to sooner identify unused items. So this kind of change, setting an unusdd object reference to `null`, *in theory* is not always voodoo.

Is it voodoo? There are reportedly parts of the Java library code that do this. The writers of that code are much better than average programmers and either know, or cooperate with, programmers who know details of the garbage collector implementations. So that suggests there *is* sometimes a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As you said there are optimizations, i.e. JVM knows the place when the variable was last used and the object referenced by it can be GCed right after this last point (still executing in current scope). So nulling out references in most cases does not help GC.

But it can be useful to avoid "nepotism" (or "floating garbage") problem ([read more here](http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2016/03/gc-nepotism-and-linked-queues.html) or [watch video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9o1LVfGp2A&feature=youtu.be&t=1391)). The problem exists because heap is split into Old and Young generations and there are different GC mechanisms applied: Minor GC (which is fast and happens often to clean young gen) and Major Gc (which causes longer pause to clean Old gen). "Nepotism" does not allow for garbage in Young gen to be collected if it is referenced by garbage which was already tenured to an Old gen.

> This is 'pathological' because ANY promoted node will result in the promotion of ALL following nodes until a GC resolves the issue.

To avoid nepotism it's a good idea to null out references from an object which is supposed to be removed. You can see this technique applied in JDK classes: [LinkedList](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/c638b7fdff8cad2fed2f71a6d230684f8311602a/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L180) and [LinkedHashMap](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#L286)

```java
private E unlinkFirst(Node<E> f) {
    final E element = f.item;
    final Node<E> next = f.next;
    f.item = null;
    f.next = null; // help GC
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doc point out "Assign null to Variables That Are No Longer Needed" https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3681/abebi/index.html