# java memory usage

Tags: java

how the java memory works whenever a new class is instantiated, and when it gets garbage
collected, etc.

And also there is difference in memory usage for the collection classes.
For eg:Vector takes more memory than hash map like that.

Comment: This question is far too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new object is instantiated it takes up memory, when it is no longer used, it frees up memory. More items you put in a collection more memory it will take. When you no longer need an object you want to set to `null`.

Comment: This probably isn't true anymore. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850878/does-setting-java-objects-to-null-do-anything-anymore

Answer (score 3):

Classes are not instantiated, rather classes are defined and objects from those classes are instantiated. when a object is instantiated using **new** operator memory is allocated.