# Can nulling a method variable make it garbage collectable?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Background: I have a method that does a bunch of fiddling with copies of a giant `List`s and I am occasionally running our of memory. All of this in a single method scope.

Question: Luckily I only need to original giant list at the beginning of the method. In my method, would setting my list to `null` allow garbage collecting it? Or does the JIT or compiler automatically dereference a variable it sees will no longer be used? I'm thinking this could be a minor optimization to allow earlier garbage collection.

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/850878/13

Comment: Clearly the start of the method does something different to the rest of the method.  I would extract the portion of the method which needs the giant list and have it fall out of scope in the extracted method.

Comment: The first of those two isn't strictly related to this as even in the olden days, returning from a function caused all the local variables in said function to be garbage collectable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to nullify a variable. An article on garbage collection (that is well worth a read) can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html). You are looking specifically for the section labeled "Explicit Nulling"

Comment: Perfect answer - thanks for a great reference.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Interesting that the article also states that even can be counterproductive to nullify variables.