# Java Nulling out Class pointers?

Tags: java, ram

I have a feeling this question will be obvious, but I think the questions should still be asked just to be safe.

If I have a class that accepts parameters, and I continuously call the same class with the same reference name, but different parameters, do I have to null out the previous class instance to prevent ram from getting eaten up with every new instance? for example

```
 RandomClass className = new RandomClass(argument1);
 while(className.classMethod() != null){
     className = new RandomClass(argument i)
     i++;
 }
```

I'm assuming The `className` with argument one would be destroyed when `className` with argument2 is called? or would I have to

```
 RandomClass className = new RandomClass(argument1);
 while(className.classMethod() != null){
     className = new RandomClass(argument i);
     className = null;
     i++;
 }
```

just to be safe?

Comment: Google "Java garbage collection"

Comment: You do not have "class pointers", you have *references* to *objects*.  The objects are *instances* of some class (eg, "RandomClass"), but this does not make them classes.  And, as suggested, study up on "garbage collection" in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does setting Java objects to null do anything anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850878/does-setting-java-objects-to-null-do-anything-anymore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to null variables, new java and C#/C++ engines will take care of garbage collection and RAM would not be lost.

Comment: Not C.  C is not garbage collected, and it can't be in general.  (So-called conservative collectors for C rely on assumptions about the way that a program handles pointer values.)

Comment: you're right I meant recent C# C++ compilers. In the old days of C stack overflow was something that really happened :)

Answer (score 3):

Before entering the loop, you have

```
className --> 1234 // an identifier of the object for our purposes
```

After the loop has iterated one

```
className --> 9542
```

The variable `className` is referencing a different object and now your program no longer holds a referenced to the object with identifier 1234. It will therefore be garbage collected eventually. You don't need to assign `null` to the variable. (There are some extremely rare cases where you would, but don't go looking for trouble with those yet.)

Comment: Thank you both. Wish I could vote both, but sorry Sotirios, I'm gonna give it to Rusty since he's only got 98 rep. Hope you understand

Comment: @user3256725 You don't have to apologize, just make sure you understand the concepts.