# Should I delete the OnClickListener in onDestroyView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-memory, butterknife

I set listener for my button:

```
  View onCreateView(...) {
    ...
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some work
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

If I use ButterKnife, it is recommended to call `ButterKnife.unbind(this)` in `onDestroyView(){..}`. Do I need to remove the listeners for avoid memory leak?

```
void onDestroyView() {
    ...
    btn.setOnClickListener(null)
}
```

Comment: If you are using `ButterKnife` then why are you using this way to set `onClickListener`? You should use `@OnClick(R.id.myBtn)` annotation.

Comment: I know it. I just decided to check out this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends...

**Do you have different layouts for portrait and landscape, and you have it configured so that when you rotate only the view is destroyed?**

If so, **YES** to prevent references of an unused view on a used Activity/Fragment (that could prevent it from being GC)

If when you **rotate the view and Fragment/Activity is destroyed**, then **NO** you don't need to do it, the GC will take care of it.

*This difference exists due to the fact that Android uses a Mark-Sweep algorithm on it's GC which will prevent the cases where 2 unused objects with references to each other (circular references) from being collected... but **not** the cases where a used object has a referenced to an unused one*.

---

Some useful Q&A about this:

- [Does setting Java objects to null do anything anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850878/does-setting-java-objects-to-null-do-anything-anymore)
- [Android: Is there any advantage of settings references to null when an Activity is being destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128124/android-is-there-any-advantage-of-settings-references-to-null-when-an-activity)
- [Technical details of Android Garbage Collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818869/technical-details-of-android-garbage-collector)
- [How does garbage collection work in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean Dalvik?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-work-in-Android-4-2-Jelly-Bean-Dalvik-please-see-the-comment)